# Useful personal assistant

Tags: c++, cross-platform, programming, operating-system, artificial-intelligence

So before I get anyone being patronizing, I understand that this is a big project and realize that it will take years of learning and hard work.

My plan is to create an assistant that runs through all of my devices simultaneously, sort of like the Jarvis from Iron Man. The idea is that it will run on a PC connected to my home network and I will customize all of my other hardware to access it (almost like a cloud-based operating system). I will then work on the 'smart home' implications later, but the idea is to code this as a hobby for as long as it takes (I really don't care how long you think it will take). Could anyone recommend what languages I should use to do this and what, if any, development packages, might prove useful.

I am learning C++ and plan to learn Java in the near future.

Comment: Hi David Maxwell, welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within [the scope defined on meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/23377) and in the [help center](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Python is rapidly rising in the ranks to become one of the most popular programming languages. It's very versatile. Java is another great language to learn because it is still used basically everywhere.

However, the choice of which programming language to use is really up to you. For example, if you're a great C programmer but not that experienced in the Kotlin language, then your program would most likely be a better program if you code it with C since you would theoretically understand the language more. If you coded your program in Kotlin, there may be more bugs in the program because you are not that familiar with the Kotlin syntax.

I personally recommend the Java language because it is well-known, industry-recognized and runs on a range of devices, from an Android phone to a Windows app to your Volkswagen automobile, and maybe even your microwave. Based on the information you provided in your question, Java might be the better choice for you.